# Log4j2 RollingFileAppender builder methods wrong return type

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, builder, rollingfileappender

using Log4j2 library version 2.9.1.

I am trying to create `RollingFileAppender` programmatically:

```
RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                    .withName(name)
                    .withLayout(...some layout...)
                    .withStrategy(...some strategy...)
                    .build();
```

And I couldn't compile it because it says there is no method `withStrategy` in that builder.

If I reorder method calls:

```
RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                        .withStrategy(...some strategy...)
                        .withName(name)
                        .withLayout(...some layout...)
                        .build();
```

It couldn't compile because it says there is no build() method now.
So it looks like this builder methods return some base builder instead of the same one.

Temporary workaround was to create separate method with generic parameter:

```
private <B extends RollingFileAppender.Builder<B>> RollingFileAppender createAppender() {
        return RollingFileAppender.<B>newBuilder()
                .withName("name")
                .withStrategy(...some strategy...)
                .withLayout(...some layout...)
                .build();
    }
```

Then it works fine. But this is not the usual way of using Builder.

So the question is: is this a bug and is there a better way to create RollingFileAppender without this workaround?

Comment: I just tried making one and it worked fine.  I would make sure that org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends Serializable> and org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RolloverStrategy are the base classes for the arguments.

Comment: @AlexC even RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().withName(newName).build() isn't working for me. Are you using same library version?

Comment: Yes, see below, I am pulling in 2.9.1 into an empty project.  Maybe you are accidentally picking up an older version of log4j along with 2.9.1?  Check the libraries to see if that may be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving replies to answer since I can't paste code into comment.

My Ivy import:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-core" rev="2.9.1"/>
```

So here is my code and it worked fine:

```
package org.sandbox.log4j;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RolloverDescription;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RolloverStrategy;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.ByteBufferDestination;

import java.util.Map;

public class RollingAppenderNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Layout<String> myLayout = new Layout<String>() {
            @Override
            public byte[] getFooter() {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getHeader() {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] toByteArray(LogEvent event) {
                return new byte[0];
            }

            @Override
            public String toSerializable(LogEvent event) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public String getContentType() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getContentFormat() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void encode(LogEvent source, ByteBufferDestination destination) {

            }
        };

        RolloverStrategy myStrategy = new RolloverStrategy() {
            @Override
            public RolloverDescription rollover(RollingFileManager manager) throws SecurityException {
            return null;
            }
        };

        RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
            .withName("MyAppender")
            .withLayout(myLayout)
            .withStrategy(myStrategy)
            .build();
    }
}
```

I am thinking that the strategy object may not be using the correct base class and confusing the compiler.  What are the base classes are you using for your layout and strategy?

Comment: Ok, now I see that the problem is in the intellij idea. It says it wouldn't compile but it compiles...